Pushing dataframe to Azure SQL DB table with sqlalchemy
I had a python script to push data frames to Azure SQL DB that was working fine. I now use a new computer and I had to update python and packages used such as sqlalchemy etc
Now, the script is executing, but for the part that it pushes dataframe data to SQL tables it is extremely slow, I even tried pyspark and got the same results, what has changed that is causing this, here is the code:
con_str = (
    'Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
    'SERVER=myserver.database.windows.net;'
    'Database=mydb;'
    'UID=myuserid;'
    'PWD=mypw;'
    'Trusted_Connection=no;'
)


# create engine
connection_uri = f'mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={urllib.parse.quote_plus(con_str)}'
engine = sa.create_engine(connection_uri, fast_executemany=True)

conn_sa=engine.connect()

df_projects_2.to_sql("WfProjects", engine, schema="wf", if_exists="append", index=False)


Please check upgrading driver

This is how I resolved the issue:
1- saved all packages in requirements.txt using python freeze from the old computer
2- created a new virtual environment in the new system
3- installed the same python (older version) in the new virtual environment
4- installed all the packages using the requirements.txt
